# Where can I find an exhaustive reference of the Views module

Tags: views

I am new to the views module and am trying to get my head around how it works and what the possibilities are with it. Is there a resource, book, video tutorial, or site somewhere that does a good job of explaining the whole module from beginning to end?

Comment: Here some things to start with http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views, http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/, http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129, http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/index.html

Comment: You should post that as an answer, then I can upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some things to start with:

- http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views
- http://views-help.doc.logrus.com
- http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129
- http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/index.html

And some nonfree stuff:

- http://store.lullabot.com/products/learning-views

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent tutorial: http://nodeone.se/blogg/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone-0

Comment: That looks like a brilliant resource at first glance. Thanks so much I'll go through it over the next few days.

Comment: It was indeed a fantastic tutorial. So thanks again.

Comment: +1 Using Views as an RSS reader tutorial is good. That's my findings so far. Looking good...